# System of homogeneous linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization, simplex

I try to find conditions under which the linear system of inequalities
$$
(S):\ Ax\ge0,\ x\ge0
$$

has a solution $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not zero ($x\neq0$). Here $A$ is a $n\times n$ square matrix with real entries. Of course I could combine the two inequalities in (S)  into one and write it in the form of $\tilde{A}x\ge0$ where $\tilde{A}$ is $2n\times n$.

I assume this problem has long been addressed. Any suggestion on how to attack this problem is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can formulate general conditions for it. Saying that this system will have a solution means that it defines a non-empty feasible set. In particular, it means that $A\mathbf{x}\geq\mathbf{0}$ is non-empty in the non-negative orthant. Finding a feasible point can be formulated as an LP itself, there it requires an iterative scheme

Comment: @iarbel84 Of course (S) has the solution $x=0$. The article I got this from mentions that if (S) does not have a solution then one can use something called Stiemke's theorem

Comment: But you wanted a solution for which $x\neq 0$. As this is a linear program on its own I don't think general conditions for it apply. You have to iteratively solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(S) is equivalent to
$$
[A\ -I_n]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
b
\end{array}\right]
=0,\ \left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
b
\end{array}\right]\ge0\ \mathrm{and}\ \left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
b
\end{array}\right]\neq0\ (\Leftrightarrow\ x\neq0)
$$
According to Gordan’s theorem if (S) does not have solutions then there is $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\left[\begin{array}{c}
A^{T}\\
-I_{n}
\end{array}\right]y<0$ which comes to $y>0$ and $A^Ty<0$.